# Maintain a Single table to store logs

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

For every row in every table in my database, I want to store these 4 fields: `CreatedDate`, `ModifiedDate`, `CreatedByUserID`, `ModifiedByUserID`

The solution I have thought is to create a separate table called `Logs` and in this table I have a field `ParentTableID` and `TableName` besides above mentioned 4 fields.

This way I created only a single table to store logs in one place.

Now what could be the best way to make sure in EntityFramework that on every insert and update an entry is made in the `Logs` table?

Thanks.

Comment: Ugh I would avoid that approach. You are now forced to maintain the same datatype of every primary key in your entire database. And it is just ugly. I would add those columns to all of the tables you want to audit that information for.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that this log table will grow very quick.

Comment: You gain nothing by putting the modified by and modified date in the separate table and make your system more difficult for your development staff. One could argue about created fields because they would never change after the initial insert. If this is for audit purposes though, why not track only the modified date and user? On a row insert, those values would be the creator/date.